# What is the most concise programming language?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

What is the most concise programming language? 
in case a criteria is needed for conciseness: on balance requires the least amount of characters to create any given program.

Comment: how do i make it a wiki?

Comment: Really a hard question, but I would go for compressed assembly:)

Comment: Can programs make use of the language's RTL?

Comment: @David: edit -> under the textfield there is a checkbox to the right

Comment: If this becomes wiki, I'd reopen...

Comment: Iota, Jot and Zot languages are Turing tarpits, they use only two characters used for only two operations.

Comment: Just use base 128 binary :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

APL, hands down.

Game of life in one line:

[image]
<sub>(source: [catpad.net](http://catpad.net/michael/APLLife.gif))</sub>

Comment: this will be almost a page in LaTeX:D

Comment: That's cheating! When your character set is million characters (like it seems in this case) it's unfair to compete with languages constrained to alphanumeric and punctuation :)

Comment: The APL character set is a reasonable size. You just can't type it on a normal keyboard.

Comment: Hands down: `{≢⍸⍵}⌺3 3∊¨3+0,¨⊢` [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=GoL%20%u2190%20%7B%u2262%u2378%u2375%7D%u233A3%203%u220A%A83+0%2C%A8%u22A2%20%20%u22C4%20%20w%20%u2190%20%u2191%280%201%200%200%29%280%200%201%200%29%281%201%201%200%29%280%200%200%200%29%20%20%u22C4%20%20%28w%29%20%28GoL%20world%29&run)

Answer (score 11):

[J](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_%28programming_language%29), a descendant of APL.

Sample J implementation of quicksort (whitespace for clarity):

```
quicksort =: (($:@(<#[) , (=#[) , $:@(>#[)) ({~ ?@#)) ^: (1<#)
```

Comment: @mmyers: Maybe try squinting?

Comment: Are you sure that's not some kind of totem-pole smiley?

Comment: @RD1 - +1 for totem pole smiley!

Comment: May I add an inline comment to show the feeling of its readability? `NB. @_@  >_<`

Answer (score 10):

I think it's APL (or one of its dialects). For example, to find all primes between 1 and R, this code works:

```
(~R∊R∘.×R)/R←1↓⍳R
```

However, to a daily use, I think any functional language (F#, for example) is very concise, since you only express what you want to do, not how.

Comment: “Express what you want to do, not how” is not a description of functional languages, but of declarative ones, like Prolog. And even there, it's only 90% correct.

Comment: I think it's more correct to describe functional languages as "describing what the solution 'looks' like" rather than how to find the solution.. At least that's what I gathered from my limited Haskell experience

Answer (score 9):

[The Whitespace programnming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29) only allows three characters (space, tab, and newline).

Comment: Yeah, three characters are good, but two are getter:D Look at the Iota, Jot and Zot languages:
http://esolangs.org/wiki/Jot

Comment: You took the question wrong. This is one of the least concise languages. It is the opposite of what is asked.

Comment: It is the most concise language to the naked eye.

Comment: space-space-space-tab-space-tab-tab-linefeed is the binary number 0001011, which is 11 in decimal. How is that concise? It's the OPPOSITE of concise.

"Concise" doesn't mean there are few characters in the language. "Concise" means it takes few characters to DO something.

Answer (score 5):

Binary.

The zeroes and ones are then interpreted as x86 code.

There really isn't a good answer here

Comment: you should really see the Iota language:)

Comment: the binary number 0001011 is 11 in decimal. How is that concise? It's the OPPOSITE of concise. "Concise" doesn't mean there are few characters in the language. "Concise" means it takes few characters to DO something.

Answer (score 1):

As yassin pointed out, for daily use, functional programming languages offer more terseness. Haskell seems a great example: the "xmonad" window manager was written in less than 1000 lines of code!

While not directly related to the question, it's also interesting to know that xmonad doesn't crash, because a theorem prover was run over the code to *prove* it wouldn't crash! [1](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1253618)

Answer (score -2):

brain itself, current programming language isn't concise/compact enough.

may be future programming language much like brain itself.

just like what deep learning archives in vision classification area.